# How can I speed up my regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm writing a script to change all the urls of my content over to a new place.

```
var regex = /.*cloudfront.net/
var pDistro = "newDistro.cloudfront.net/"

for(var i=0;i<strings.length;i++){
    strings[i] = strings[i].replace(regex,pDistro);
}
```

The strings I'm doing `replace` on average about 140 characters each. They're urls that follow the format: `https://[thing to replace].cloudfront.net/[something]/[something]/[something]`

But this operation is terribly slow, taking about 4.5 seconds to process an average-sized array.

Why is this so slow? How can I make this faster?

If this question would be better suited to the codereview stack exchange, or some other site, let me know and I'll move it there.

### EDIT:

The data, as it appeared in the db I was pulling from appeared to be 140 characters. During the pull process, some virtualization happened and appended 400 more characters onto the string, so no wonder the regex takes so long.

The 140-character-string loop takes considerably less time, as others have pointed out.

The moral of the story: "Make sure the data you have is what you expect it to be" and "If your regex is taking too long, use smaller strings and a more specific regex (i.e. no wildcard)"

Comment: What is an average-sized array?

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah around 10 elements of 140 characters each.

Comment: can you provide the sample code & data to verify suggestion..

Comment: By default, the kleene star is greedy: The `.*` will first try to match the entire string, then the entire string minus 1 character, etc., until it can match the rest. That's probably why it is so slow. Apart from the solution from iismathwizard, you could also gain time by appending a `?` to the star to make it non-greedy. (Although this is unneccesary in iismathwizard's solution (it will even slow it down slightly there.))

Comment: @vinayakj sure, but I'll have to scramble some urls first

Comment: just console the `strings` variable and copy paste it here

Comment: It takes a few milliseconds in Chrome's console to do this on an array of a 1000 120+ character strings. Granted they're randomly generated and have some numbers  before the ".cloudfront.net" part, but it shouldn't take that long no matter what the strings look like. Is it possible that the delay is coming from somewhere else?

Comment: right.. and as per OP its just _around 10 elements of 140 characters each_  so my guess is there is something else that is also consuming the time

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah oh wow, lemme try and replicate in jsfiddle or something. I'll also use semi-real data to

Comment: @vinayakj, you're right. My strings were actually 500 characters long, as some virtualization tampered with the strings as I was pulling from the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps it would run a little faster like this:

```
https:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.cloudfront\.net
```

Generally, the more exclusive your character sets are the faster the regular expression will run.

---

Thanks to @sbedulin for providing a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/cloudfront-regex-replace) link

Comment: That seemed to shave off about a half of a second. Maybe this is just one of those things that take a long time to do, and there's little that can be done about it?

Comment: @Houseman it really shouldn't be running that slowly even with your regular expression. Is this a particularly slow machine that you're using?

Comment: 16GB ram, i7m processor, no, it should be fast enough. Weird

Comment: @Houseman i think something else in your code is taking this time up because it really shouldn't be the regular expressions in this case.

Comment: You're right. My strings were actually 500+ characters long, not 140 as I had thought.

Comment: @Houseman jsperf shows the speed of more exclusive RegExps http://jsperf.com/cloudfront-regex-replace

Comment: @sbedulin i've never seen this before. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Welcome! feel free to modify it

Comment: How about replacing `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with `[^\n]`? Surely one check is quicker than possibly three..

Comment: @TomBurris Nope. Actually slower. Like I said: The more exclusive, the better. https://jsperf.com/test-of-n-on-cloudfront/1

Answer (score 6):

For such a simple replacement, a regex is likely not the fastest search and replace.  For example, if you replace the search with `.indexOf()` and then use `.slice()` to do the replacement, you can speed it up 12-50x (depending upon browser).

I wasn't sure of the exact replacement logic you want to simulate, but here's a non-regex method that is a lot faster:

```
var pos, str, target = "cloudfront.net/";
var pDistro = "https://newDistro.cloudfront.net/"
for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
    str = urls[i];
    pos = str.indexOf(target);
    if (pos !== -1) {
        results[i] = pDistro + str.slice(pos + target.length);
    }
}
```

Adding in the more intelligent regex replacement suggested by others, here's a comparison.  The more intelligent regex definitely helps the regex, but it is still slower than just using `.indexOf()` and `.slice()` and the difference is the most pronounced in Firefox:

See jsperf here: http://jsperf.com/fast-replacer

[image]

Comment: Here is a comparison with RegExp suggested by @iismathwizard http://jsperf.com/cloudfront-regex-replace-vs-splice

Comment: @sbedulin - I updated your jsperf to the latest version of my code (as in my answer now) and added a subdomain to the test URLs since that's what we're trying to replace and the results changed: http://jsperf.com/cloudfront-regex-replace-vs-splice/2

Comment: Thanks! `indexOf+splice` is really fast in Firefox, other browsers leave a room to make a decision

Comment: @sbedulin - I updated my jsperf and the graph in my answer to show the smarter regex replace.

Comment: While indexOf+splice may be faster for small strings, it's exponentially slower for very large strings. Be sure to benchmark for your own use case.

Comment: @IsaacLyman - This is also a 9 year old post.  This micro-optimization stuff tends to change over time as the JS engines evolve.